# Why can't you use a memory address of an unhashable type as a key for a dict?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I understand that since unhashable types like lists are mutating, they cannot be used as a key for hashing. However, I don't see why their memory address (which I don't believe changes) can be used?

For example:

```
my_list = [1,2,3]
my_dict = {my_list: 1} #error
my_dict = {id(my_list): 1} # no error
```

Comment: Those are sets not dicts. Plus `id()` return an `int` so why shouldn't it work?

Comment: You are hashing an integer.

Comment: You *can*, easily, but `{some_list: whatever}` won't do that, because it'd break the semantics of dicts.

Answer (score 2):

You actually *can* use the memory address of an object as a hash function if you extend `list`, `set`, etc.

The primary reason using a memory address for a hash is bad is because if two objects are equal (`a == b` evaluates to `True`) we also want their hashes to be equal (`hash(a) == hash(b)` to be `True`). Otherwise, we could get unintended behavior.

To see an example of this, let's create our own class that extends `list` and use the memory address of the object as a hash function.

```
>>> class HashableList(list):
        def __hash__(self):
            return id(self)  # Returns the memory address of the object
```

Now we can create two hashable lists! Our `HashableList` uses the same constructor as python's built-in list.

```
>>> a = HashableList((1, 2, 3))
>>> b = HashableList((1, 2, 3))
```

Sure enough, as we would expect, we get

```
>>> a == b
True
```

And we can hash our lists!

```
>>> hash(a)
1728723187976
>>> hash(b)
1728723187816
>>> hash(a) == hash(b)
False
```

If you look at the last 3 digits, you'll see `a` and `b` are close to each other in memory, but aren't in the same location. Since we're using the memory address as our hash, that also means their hashes aren't equal.

What happens if compare the built in hash of two equal tuples (or any other hashable object)?

```
>>> y = ('foo', 'bar')
>>> z = ('foo', 'bar')
>>> y == z
True
>>> hash(y)
-1256824942587948134
>>> hash(z)
-1256824942587948134
>>> hash(y) == hash(z)
True
```

If you try this on your own, your hash of `('foo', 'bar')` won't match mine, since the hashes of strings changes every time a new session of python starts. The important thing is that, in the same session `hash(y)` will always equal `hash(z)`.

Let's see what happens if we make a set, and play around with the `HashableList` objects and the tuples we made.

```
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add(a)
>>> s.add(y)
>>> s
{[1, 2, 3], ('foo', 'bar')}

>>> a in s  # Since hash(a) == hash(a), we can find a in our set
True
>>> y in s  # Since hash(y) == hash(y), we can find y in our set
True
>>> b in s
False
>>> z in s
True
```

Even though `a == b`, we couldn't find `a` in the set because `hash(b)` doesn't equal `hash(a)`, so we couldn't find our equivalent list in the set!